# SpringBoot 2.x, JUnit 5 extension, and MongoClient

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, junit5

I am trying to write an extension for JUnit 5 and was curious if there is a way for me to tap into the mongodb connection that `@SpringBootTest` already set up for the test.

So, for example, my extension looks like this:

```
public class MyExtension implements BeforeTestExecutionCallback {

  @Override
  public void beforeTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
    // How do I get at the MongoClient here (or in the class constructor)?
  }
}
```

I can create a new one, of course, but I'd like to reuse the one Spring already set up so the extension won't have to deal with knowing information like URI, auth credentials, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SpringExtension` class provides a method for getting `ApplicationContext` associated with the supplied `ExtensionContext`. 
Then you can get the bean from the `ApplicationContext` like this:

```
public class MyExtension implements BeforeTestExecutionCallback {

    @Override
    public void beforeTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(context);
        MongoClient mongoClient = applicationContext.getBean(MongoClient.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG. I can't believe I didn't see that. I've crawled that class up and down trying to figure out how they are doing it and somehow missed what was staring me right in the face. LOL. Thank you!